# Nodejs + Expressjs + Angularjs Empty Mysql Select Result

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I am building an application using angularjs nodejs expressjs and mysql.

Right now i am facing a problem where i am getting empty response from Node while in the node console i saw it successfully retrieve the data from mysql.

**angularjs**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $resource, Map) {
  $scope.fetchdata = {};
  var Fetchdata = $resource('http://localhost:8080/fetchnote');
  Fetchdata.query(function(results) {
      $scope.fetchdata = results;
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.fetchdata));
})
```

**nodejs**

```
app.get('/fetchnote', function(req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * from note', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(rows);
            res.json(rows);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

if i pass `http://localhost:8080/fetchnote` directly to the browser address bar, then it would show all records, same goes to the node console, saw all records, while not in angularjs. No error in javascript console as well, just empty records.

Anyone can give some idea?

Comment: are you facing any cross domain issue in network console?

Comment: nope, no error at all.

Comment: Why don't you do an http get request  in angular  to match the verb in node of using resource?

Comment: @ArrowHead would you please show me how? kinda new to this stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $resource, Map) {
  $scope.fetchdata = {};
  var Fetchdata = $resource('http://localhost:8080/fetchnote');
  Fetchdata.query(function(results) {
      $scope.fetchdata = results;
      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.fetchdata));
  })
})
```

In the browser you can press F12 and see the network tab what requests are made (filter for xhr). I prefer Chrome as that has a nice preview of json resonses.

Comment: can you confirm that the data is returned from the xhr while calling from angular? You can view the response at Network-> XHR Tab of chrome dev tools

Comment: @JosephGoh take a closer look at the position of console.log in your code and in this answer.

Comment: @PaulsonPeter okay, i see the diff now, but why can't i access it outside `Fetchdata.query(...` ? If i can't access it, this mean i can't do anything with the data which i want iterate it.

Comment: It is an ajax/ asynchronous request. The codes written below will be executed before getting the result of ajax call.